# Finding the solution for $Ax=0$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Find the solution for $Ax=0$ for the following $3 \times 3$ matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}3 & 2& -3\\ 2& -1&1 \\ 1& 1& 1\end{pmatrix}$$

I found the row reduced form of that matrix, which was

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2/3& -1\\ 0& 1&-9/7 \\ 0& 0& 1\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do next to find the "unique" solution besides $x=0$? Do I further reduce that matrix to the identity matrix?

Comment: $0$ *is* the unique solution.

Comment: You can tell at a glance (call it 3D intuition) that the matrix is not singular. The vectors 3 2 1, 2 -1 1, and -3 1 1 "obviously" point in different directions. None is a multiple of any of the other three, and they do not lie in the same plane.  A quick and dirty check, also, is to calculate the determinant, which for a 3x3 matrix of 1 digit numbers, you can do in your head with a little practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now if you imagine   that  our  vector solution is
$x=x_1,x_2,x_3$

than we will get

$x_3=0$

$x_1+(2*x_2)/3=0$

$x_2=0$

so after inserting $x_3,x_2$   into first you get $x_1=0$

Answer (score 6):

You have shown that matrix is non singular (or invertible), so that the only solution, as you state, is ${\bf x}=0$.

Answer (score 5):

First note that any linear system of the form $\mathbf{Ax} = \mathbf{0}$ has either one solution (which is $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$) or infinite solutions. In your case, once you reduce $\mathbf{A}$ to row-echelon form, none of the entries on the leading diagonal are zero. This means your matrix is invertible.

Hence, the only solution is $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$